# CustomValidator not firing in control

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, customvalidator

So here is the issue. I have a DropDownList in a .ascx control with a CustomValidator on it. This control has a ValidationGroup set by a property in the PageLoad. The button that triggers the validation is in a another file that uses this control. The problem is that the server side validation is never getting fired. I add breakpoints in it and they are never hit. Anyone have any thoughts about what is going on? Here is the code:

Dropdown.ascx:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestions" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cvddlQuestions" OnServerValidate="cvddlQuestions_ServerValidate"
         ErrorMessage="* Parent question is required." ValidateEmptyText="true" Display="Dynamic" />
    </p>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cvddlQuestions.ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup; 
    //ValidationGroup is a property in the parent file that is being set on PageLoad
}

protected void cvddlQuestions_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;// (ddlQuestions.SelectedValue != "-1");
}
```

In the parent file that uses Dropdown.ascx I have this button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnQuestionAdd" runat="server" OnClick="btnQuestionAdd_Click" 
    ValidationGroup="editQuestion" CommandName="add" />
```

Parent files code behind:

```
protected void btnQuestionAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("editQuestion");
    if (Page.IsValid)   //ALWAYS SEEMS TO BE TRUE
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

When I add a client validation function to the customvalidator it fires no problem. But the page is ALWAYS returning as valid. I have tried adding a ControlToValidate and setting ValidateEmptyText="true" and I still get the same result. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer was something incredibly stupid. When I instantiated the control that all this code was within I had to set the ValidationGroup property on the front end rather than the back end.

Lets say the code I posted was within a .ascx file called QuestionControl.ascx. After registering the control on my page I had to write the following:

```
<asp:QuestionControl runat="server" id="qcPage" ValidationGroup="editQuestion" />
```

No idea why saying:

```
qcPage.ValidationGroup = "editQuestion";
```

didn't work since the property was only a string.

Answer (score 3):

Set DropDownList's [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.causesvalidation.aspx)-Property to `true`, default is `false`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuestions" CausesValidation="True" CssClass="if" DataTextField="Question" DataValueField="iD" runat="server">
```

And you also have to set it's Validationgroup property accordingly(see property below).

A side note: You don't need the member variable `ValidationGroup` in your UserControl. Just use a public property `ValidationGroup` that directly set/get the Validator's ValidationGroup property. On this way you don't need to set it on every postback since it's stored in ViewState anyway and you could also set it in the UserControl itself if you want.

```
public string ValidationGroup {
    get { return cvddlQuestions.ValidationGroup; }
    set { cvddlQuestions.ValidationGroup = value; ddlQuestions.ValidationGroup=value; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make a difference :( Thanks for the suggestion on the property though, sounds like a good suggestion